# Getting error in type access in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

```
export type FlowColumnNew = DefaultColumn | EntityFlowColumn | CustomColumn;

export type DefaultColumn = {
  name: string;
  defaultValue: GenericValue;
};

export type EntityFlowColumn = {
  name: string;
  alias: string;
  source: string;
  displayName: string;
  defaultValue: GenericValue;
};

export type CustomColumn = {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  source: string;
};
const activeColumns:FlowColumnNew = []

const isEntityExist = activeColumns.some(
            (column: FlowColumnNew) =>
              column.name === entity.column.name &&
              column.source === entity.column.source &&
              column.$type === entity.column.$type,
          )`
```

My code is working but I am getting "Property 'source' does not exist on type 'FlowColumnNew'." in React build.

Comment: Well, it doesn't. Not in all of the members of the union, anyway - it's telling you the right thing, your code isn't type safe.

Comment: Please review [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem". The current title is of little use to anyone who is having the same problem.

Comment: And please include an actual [mre]. What is `GenericValue`? What is `entity`? Where is the `$type` property coming from? Also, `activeColumns` should probably be `FlowColumnNew[]` (an _array_ type).